# Excel: Pictures Included. Reference Cell Value to Comment Box & Automatic Alerts to email Request

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I need help with two items for my project. I've searched but can only find posts about more complex questions than mine or others that I don't understand.

1. I'm trying to get the comments that I enter on one sheet to appear on a cleaner sheet being sheet 1. [Image of what I would like to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ltjC.jpg)
2. I would like to make an automatic email alert that sends me info from a cell to my email by a certain date and time. [Here is an image of what I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGtKn.jpg)

Thank you for looking!

**EDIT 6/22/18**

I didn't know how to add an image to the comment so adding here. 
@ J.Doe I tried my best changing what I could. Doesn't seem to work for me. I'm not to familiar with VBA so just took my best shot at it. I added an extra image that shows what the actual cells are and sheet names. To help make my question clearer

```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N4:N48")) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then
        Dim P1 As Range: Set P1 = Sheets("Solutions").Cells(Target.Row, 1)
        If Not P1.Comment Is Nothing Then
            If Target.Value = "" Then
                P1.Comment.Delete
            Else
                P1.Comment.Text Format(Target, "@")
            End If
        Else
            P1.AddComment Format(Target, "@")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

[sheets with correct names and cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbUSh.jpg)

Comment: A search on here would give you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31191030/4961700

Comment: Sorry it's a bit confusing, in your first image you say you want to roll over column A. But in the third image you use Cell F42-45. The code is working fine, just putting the comments sheets "Solutions", column A. The last `1` in: `Set P1 = Sheets("Solutions").Cells(Target.Row, 1)` is the column index than you can change depending on where you want the comments to be added.

Comment: You are asking two separate questions as one question. Consider moving point 2 into a new question.

Answer (score 0):

For your first point:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N:N")) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then
        Dim P1 As Range: Set P1 = Sheets(1).Cells(Target.Row, 1)
        If Not P1.Comment Is Nothing Then
            If Target.Value = "" Then
                P1.Comment.Delete
            Else
                P1.Comment.Text Format(Target, "@")
            End If
        Else
            P1.AddComment Format(Target, "@")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

To be placed directly in your sheet2 code.

Adapt `Sheets(1).Cells(Target.Row, 1)` to the sheet that need the "excel comment"

This will not deal with multiple cell changes at once (e.g. you delete all comments in sheet2 range N2:N11)

Your point 2 sound very tricky...

Comment: Thank You J.Doe! I tried changing the code but I think I missed something. I added a picture of the actual cell location on the original post and sheet names. I'd appreciate it if you could see if this is what I was supposed to do.